# How to align fixed grid view header with my codes?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a problem here which after applying fixed grid view header it does not align with my grid view data. Before the I code it to fixed the header, the grid view columns align well with the column data.
The following is the sample problem I am facing:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

The scroll bar pushes the datagrid to the side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved with reference to:

http://www.dotnetbull.com/2011/11/scrollable-gridview-with-fixed-headers.html

Answer (score 0):

Long time ago I struggled also with fixed headers on grid views.
After various efforts I switched finally to a client side solution using JQuery and the [StickyTableHeaders-Plugin](https://github.com/jmosbech/StickyTableHeaders). It works very good.

After embedding JQuery and the plugin, you just need to create the plain table server side and the plugin does the rest with a single JS line:

```
$("#tableId").stickyTableHeaders();
```

Various options are available.

[Live Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jmosbech/stFcx/)