# Freeze Column and Header of Gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have gridview like picture below.

[image]

I need to freeze header of my gridview and a cell. When I scroll the page vertically, the header's position fix on top. When I scroll horizontally, the specific column freeze and become the first column like below

[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: do you search on internet , there are many ideas on how to do that.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32820751/how-to-align-fixed-grid-view-header-with-my-codes

Comment: @Aristos Of course I browse,but I only find on how to make fix header. I didn't find any solution with my horizontal scroll problem.

Comment: with css & javascript you can do that - not the best solution

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution: create a duplicate copy of the the grid, lets call it grid2.

Right after setting the datasource of the original grid, set the datasource of `grid2` to `originalgrid.Rows[0];` then bind the `grid2`

```
grid2.dataSource = OriginalGrid.Rows[0]
grid2.Bind()
```